# How to get entire list after applying filter on stream of data in java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

How to get entire list after applying filter on stream of data in java 8:
Like I have List of integers and applied filter, below code snippet gives me only filtered data but I want entire list after alteration:

I want to  have gradeListMod with all values of gradeList with few filters like : if gradeList contain value greater than 38 and is not multiple of 5  then round it off to multiple of 5. Then return list with all values

```
    ex: if list has 35,67,89,30 
    then I want gradeListMod filled with : 35,70,90,30

List<Integer> gradeListMod= gradeList.stream().filter(mark->mark>38)
                          .filter(mark->(mark%5))
                          .map(mark->mark+(5-mark%5))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If you want original list, do not use filters.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do here? How do you want the `gradeList` to change?

Comment: gradeList is also  constructed with <Integer>

Comment: You can't, not like that.  But you could say `map(mark -> if (...) { return ... } else { return mark; })`

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do, you just need one `map` method. `filter` is not suitable here because you can't get the filtered items back later on in the pipeline.

In the `map` method, you should use an old-school if statement to check for the conditions.

```
gradeList.stream().map(mark -> {
    if (mark > 38 && mark % 5 != 0) {
        return mark+(5-mark%5);
    } else {
        return mark;
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```